# Best data structure to efficiently allow pull of all ranges (min,max) such that value >= min and value <= max?

Tags: data-structures

Imagine that I have a set of min values and max values. I want a data structure that, given an outside value, will most efficiently give me the (min,max) pairs for which value >= min, value <= max.

If you know the ranges are non-overlapping, I imagine you could just do a balanced binary search tree on min, and the first node that has a (min,max) that is satisfied has to be the only one. But if the ranges can overlap, is there a data structure that can let you do this efficiently?

Comment: what sort of data values are being used?  ints? doubles? floats? strings?

Comment: Can't a List just do this in O(n)? `foreach(pair) check max and min; push on answer;`

Comment: EvilTeach: These will be integers or longs. nonnb: I'm not using an RDBMS, or else that is what I would do...the issue, in fact, is that I cannot use an RDBMS and am trying to implement the speed boost that an index would give. Marnix: In the non-overlapping case, for example, you'd get a significant speed boost over that by using a BST because you'd go to O(ln(n)), and the datasets are quite large. I am going for maximum efficiency here. Making the index or data structure, ideally, is just overhead at the beginning which lets the later operations run much faster.

Comment: Are there limits to the size of the ranges.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are describing is also known as "**stabbing query**". It is well described in graphics-programming text-books, where this is a very relevant problem.

Also, the wikipedia page on [segment trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) might help. Those trees are the data structure that is commonly used to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer might actually be this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree. Given a point or a set of points, it allows you to efficiently pull satisfying intervals. The only caveat, of course, being that the construction of the initial data structure is not efficient, but that's also inevitable in any indexing etc.

Comment: This seems to be the correct solution. The interval tree wiki exactly describes your requirement

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to put the (min,max) in an array, and sort by mind
Then use binary search to find the area in the array where the mins meet the criteria then search.

Comment: I thought about this approach, but was wondering if there might be a way to avoid doing a full search on the array where the mins meet the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The query can be solved with a [Range Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree): [a binary tree of binary trees](http://books.google.dk/books?id=vO-NRRKHG84C&lpg=PA14&ots=fYGg-nTFTs&dq=bentley%20range%20tree&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q=bentley%20range%20tree&f=false).

The outer tree is a search tree on the values x of the pairs (x, y). The pairs (x, y) are stored in the leaf nodes. Each node V of the outer tree contains a pointer to a y-indexed search tree Y, containing all the pairs of the subtree of V.

To solve a range query ([Value, infinity) = RangeX, RangeY), search down the outer search tree for the leftmost x<sub>min</sub> satisfying Value <= x<sub>min</sub>. Let V be a node on the path to x<sub>min</sub>. If the search goes to the left, then the search tree Y of the *right* subtree of V contains pairs that are all in RangeX. Add all pairs of Y that are in RangeY to the result.