# How to find subarray between min and max

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have a Sorted array .Lets assume

`{4,7,9,12,23,34,56,78}`  Given min and max I want to find elements in array between min and max in efficient way.

```
Cases:min=23 and max is 78  op:{23,34,56,78}
 min =10 max is 65 op:{12,23,34,56}

min 0 and max is 100 op:{4,7,9,12,23,34,56,78}

Min 30 max= 300:{34,56,78}

Min =100 max=300 :{} //empty
```

I want to find efficient way to do this?I am not asking code any algorithm which i can use here like DP exponential search?

Comment: Duplicate (or perhaps subset) of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817797/best-data-structure-to-efficiently-allow-pull-of-all-ranges-min-max-such-that?rq=1

Comment: Why is 9 in op when min = 10? Would a binary search for min and max work? - Just saw @paxdiablo post, it does the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's sorted, you can easily find the lowest element greater than or equal to the minimum desired, by using a binary search over the entire array.

A binary search basically reduces the serch space by half with each iteration. Given your first example of `10`, you start as follows with the midpoint on the `12`:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 <- index
 4  7  9 12 23 34 56 78
         ^^
```

Since the element you're looking at is higher than 10 and the next lowest is lesser, you've found it.

Then, you can use a similar binary search but only over that section from the element you just found to the end. This time you're looking for the highest element less than or equal to the maximum desired.

On the same example as previously mentioned, you start with:

```
 3  4  5  6  7 <- index
12 23 34 56 78
      ^^
```

Since that's less than 65 and the following one is also, you need to increase the pointer to the halfway point of `34..78`:

```
 3  4  5  6  7 <- index
12 23 34 56 78
         ^^
```

And there you have it, because that number is less and the following number is more (than 65)

Then you have the start at stop indexes (3 and 6) for extracting the values.

```
 0  1  2    3  4  5  6    7 <- index
 4  7  9 ((12 23 34 56)) 78
           -----------
```

The time complexity of the algorithm is `O(log N)`. Though keep in mind that this really only becomes important when dealing with larger data sets. If your data sets do consist of only about eight elements, you may as well use a linear search since (1) it'll be easier to write; and (2) the time differential will be irrelevant.

I tend not to worry about time complexity unless the operations are really expensive, the data set size gets into the thousands, or I'm having to do it thousands of times a second.

Comment: Like the idea of binary search

Answer (score 2):

Since it is sorted, this should do:

```
List<Integer> subarray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int n : numbers) {
    if (n >= MIN && n <= MAX) subarray.add(n);
}
```

It's O(n) as you only look at every number once.

Comment: @ThomasAhle yes but the result (subarray) would not be sorted. But of course binary search is much faster.

Comment: Ah, but it's not specified they have to be

Comment: I think it is - a subarray of a sorted array should itself be sorted, don't you think? An array implies a sort order unlike a set.